# Wordpress tabindex Order

Tags: forms

I created a form (through Contact Form 7, although I don't think that makes a difference here), and I believe Wordpress is causing some tabindex issues. I set field 1 to tabindex of 1, field 2 to tabindex 2, etc. Well, when I try to tab from field 1 to 2, it displays a popup in the top left of the screen saying "Skip to toolbar." After researching (not finding a whole lot), I set field 1 to tabindex 3, and went up 1 from there. Well, after tabindex 10 it tabbed to the top of the screen just above the nav. I then came across this page which offers a script that sets the tabindex's very high intentionally. My question is, is that semantically correct or just a work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Skip to toolbar" in the WP Navbar comes `tabindex` attribute set to 1; I really think it is correct because it is the first visual element when the navbar is active. The problem is that the HTML of the navbar isn't really the first in the source code, it is in the footer, so your form fields are first in the source code. When two elements has the same `tabindex` attribute, they are navigated in the order they appear in the character stream. So, when you set your fields with tabindex 1 and 2, you go first to your field 1 (it the first in the character stream), then to next `tabindex` 1 element (WP navbar) and then to `tabindex` 2 element (your field 2).

This issue shold not happend when the navbar is inactive.

You can start the `tabindex` of the form fields in 2 or 3, there is nothing wrong with that. The `tabindex` can have any integer value, correlative or not. You can set `tabindex` like `1, 2, 3, 4`; `10, 15, 20, 25` or `84, 12, 98` and all of them are correct.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I feel pretty embarrassed that I didn't even think about how the WP Admin navigation wouldn't be there for site visitors. I didn't realize that you could have the same tabindex appear more than once and tab from one to the other.